org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.0 shows error Input payload not found
Backend application runs on Spring boot, Gradle - 8.1.1 and Kotlin - 1.8.21.  Till Spring boot 3.1.12 all API's are working fine.  When I upgrade to 3.2.0, only one API is failing with
<200 OK OK,Input payload not found,[Content-Type:"text/plain; charset=utf-8", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked">
No changes done in API.  I can see this error only upgrading to 3.2.0. Any clue please?
build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${spring_boot_version}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version "${kotlin_version}"
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version "${kotlin_version}"
    id 'jacoco'
}



 implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-java:22.16.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.14.2'
    implementation 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.9.0'
    implementation group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20231013'
    implementation "io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:3.0.5"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1'
    implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.6"
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.5'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.5.5'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.4.14'
    implementation "net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:7.2"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.27.2'
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-spring:7.11.2"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:7.11.2"
    testImplementation "io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.11.2"
   

